# Duplicates inside list being combined rather than omitted. Conditional error

Tags: python, url, conditional-statements

What you see here is a simple sitemap generator. The problem is that whenever there is a duplicate of a link, instead of not doing anything, it seems to combine the duplicate with the next url. For example, it will say http://www.apple.comhttp://www.apple.com/sitemap

```
from time import sleep
from urllib.request import urlopen
allurl=["http://www.apple.com"]
url="http://www.apple.com"
toturl=[]
prinst=True
print("Urllib loaded")
for df in allurl:
        toturl=[]
        try:
            r = str(urlopen(url).read())
        except:
            pass
        for zr in range(0,len(r)-1):
                if r[zr]=="h" and r[zr+1]=="r" and r[zr+2]=="e" and r[zr+3]=="f"and r[zr+4]=="=" and r[zr+6]=="h":
                        for y in range(6,100000):
                                if r[zr+y]=='"':
                                        break
                                else:
                                        toturl.append(r[zr+y])
                        if "".join(toturl) not in allurl: #Conditional Being Ignored, so to speak.
                                print("".join(toturl))
                                allurl.append("".join(toturl))
                                toturl=[]
                                url=df
                                print("\n")
```

Comment: use some html-parser to parse html!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't reset `toturl` if there is a duplicate. Allways initial variables, when they are first used, not when you're done with them.

```
from time import sleep
from urllib.request import urlopen

allurl = ["http://www.apple.com"]
url = "http://www.apple.com"
prinst = True
print("Urllib loaded")

for df in allurl:
    try:
        r = str(urlopen(url).read())
    except:
        print("some exception occured!")
    else:
        for zr in range(0,len(r)-1):
            if r[zr:zr+5]=="href=" and r[zr+6]=="h":
                toturl = []
                for y in range(6,100000):
                    if r[zr+y] == '"':
                        break
                    else:
                        toturl.append(r[zr+y])
                toturl = "".join(toturl)
                if toturl not in allurl:
                    print(toturl)
                    allurl.append(toturl)
                    url = df
                    print("\n")
```